# CSS: how to create a proper 3D button?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I want to create a 3D button with black edges on every angle.

I want the black edges to appear in the corner (just like the screenshot above) as you can see on the upper right of the button, and lower left of the button

I don't mind any hacky solution, however, I dont want any svg solution.

update: code snipped is provided.

my code:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:wght@300;500;600;800&display=swap");

:root {
  --green:#3CCF4E;
  --orange: #EF5B0C;
  --yellow: #FFDE00;
  --blue: #31E1F7;
  --pink: #D800A6;
  --font: "Work Sans", sans-serif;
  --shadow-1: 1.5vmin 1.5vmin #000;
  --border: solid 1vmin #000;
  --border-small: solid 0.65vmin #000;
}
body{
  background:linear-gradient(90deg,var(--pink),var(--yellow));
}
div{
  width:fit-content;
  background-color:white;
  outline:6px solid black;
  width:210px;
  height:110px;

  
  
}

button{
  background-color:var(--green);
  height:100px;
  width:200px;
  color: #333;
  border-right:6px solid black;
  border-bottom:6px solid black;
  font-family:monospace;

}

button:hover{
  border:none;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <button>Click me</button>
</div>
```

and this is the result:

[image]

however, this is not really a 3d button (it look like a ripoff cube)

How can i create a cube button like this (with black edges)

[image]

Answer (score -2):

update.. as others suggest it already, it seam like the svg is only way [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ismail_M/c9rpfxmd/91/)

```css
:root {
  --green:#3CCF4E;
  --orange: #EF5B0C;
  --yellow: #FFDE00;
  --blue: #31E1F7;
  --pink: #D800A6;
  --font: "Work Sans", sans-serif;
  --shadow-1: 1.5vmin 1.5vmin #000;
  --border: solid 1vmin #000;
  --border-small: solid 0.65vmin #000;
}
body{
  background:linear-gradient(90deg,var(--pink),var(--yellow));
}
div{
  width:fit-content;
  background-color:#FFF;
  outline: 6px solid #bfbfbf;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
}

button{
  background-color:var(--green);
  height:100px;
  width:200px;
  color: #333;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px double #000;
  border-right:6px solid #b1b1b1;
   box-shadow: inset -6px -6px 2px 2px  black;
  border-bottom:6px solid #7c7c7c;
  font-family:monospace;

}

button:hover{
  border:none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0px 0px ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div id="main">
  <button>Click me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: the question mentioned that black edges should be there around the whole button, however, on right corner of the button, there is not black edge, same in the down side.

Comment: yeah .. I didn't notice the edges...

Comment: Just add this box-shadow: inset -6px -6px 2px 2px  black; to keep black edges, and remove it in hover.. updated

Comment: please look at the last screenshot (contact button), it is not even close to it.